# Proof that for every $n$ a certain expression is divisible by $2^n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

$a_n=\lfloor(3+\sqrt5)^n\rfloor+1$

Proof for every n that $a_n$ is divided by $2^n$ without a reminder.

I know I need to use a recursive formula since it's the subject of my assignment and I tried to finding one that it's solution is
$b_n=(3+\sqrt5)^n + (3-\sqrt5)^n$ so it will help with the proof but with no success.

Edit:
I solved the question thanks to Peter's help but I would still appreciate an answer to compare the induction. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint : The second term in the formula for $b_n$ is always between $0$ and $1$ , hence $a_n=b_n$ for all $n$

Comment: And we have $$b_1=6$$ $$b_2=28$$ $$b_n=6b_{n-1}-4b_{n-2}$$ Use induction over $n$ to prove your claim.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand now though having trouble proving that $a_n=b_n$ . I thought of defining $a_n$ as a certain number to every n and prove that $b_n$ also equal to that but I don't know what how...

Comment: First of all, in the formula for $b_n$ the first term cannot be an integer because the second is between $0$ and $1$ and the sum is an integer. Because the second term is bewteen $0$ and $1$ , $b_n$ is equal to the ceil-function of the first term , or equivalent, to the floor-function plus $1$

Comment: So I said that $a_n$ is always a round number because of the floor function and you can see that $b_n$ is also a round number from the recursion formula we found and since the second term is between 0 and 1 then its equal to the ceil-function of the first term , or equivalent, to the floor-function plus 1. Is that correct? Is that what you meant? Do you think I need to farther prove it ?

Comment: Exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I need to use a recursive formula since it's the subject of my assignment and I tried to finding one that it's solution is
>   $b_n=(3+\sqrt5)^n + (3-\sqrt5)^n$ so it will help with the proof but with no success.

If you have a linear homogenous recurrence of the form $c_n = \alpha c_{n-1} + \beta c_{n-2}$ then the standard technique to find solutions is to assume that you have a solution of the form $c_n = kx^n$, whence $kx^n = \alpha kx^{n-1} + \beta kx^{n-2}$, or $x^2 = \alpha x + \beta$. Then you find candidates for $x$ by solving the *characteristic polynomial* $x^2-\alpha x - \beta = 0$ and form the general solution to the recurrence by adding a weighted specific solution per root: i.e. $c_n = k_1 x_1{}^n + k_2 x_2{}^n$.

Here you have the second form, so you can apply the technique *in reverse*. In other words, your characteristic polynomial is $(x-3-\sqrt 5)(x-3+\sqrt 5)=0$. Multiply out to get $x^2 - 6x + 4 = 0$, so your recurrence is $b_n = 6b_{n-1} - 4b_{n-2}$.

Rewriting that as $b_n = 2(3b_{n-1}) - 2^2(b_{n-2})$ justifies the inductive step of a proof by induction that $2^n \mid b_n$, so that just leaves the identification of $a_n = b_n$ and the base cases of the induction: $b_0 = 2$ and $b_1 = 6$.